# What's the term for "double recursion"?

Tags: language-agnostic, recursion, terminology

Here's an obviously recursive function:

```
function()
{
    function();
}
```

We would simply call this "recursive"—but what about this (barely) more complex version?

```
functionLeft()
{
    functionRight();
}

functionRight()
{
    functionLeft();
}
```

Is there a term for this scenario, e.g., "double recursion"? Or is there no specific term to distinguish this case from the single-function case above?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's called [mutual recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion).

Answer (score 16):

As Jon Purdy said, the example you gave is called "mutual recursion".  The term "double recursion" also exists, but with a different meaning:  for when a function uses two recursive calls.  The classic example is the Fibonacci function"

```
int Fib(int n)
{
  if (n < 2) return 1;
  return Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2);
}
```

The Fib(n) function recursively calls itself twice.

Comment: Note that this is a crazy-inefficient way to compute fibonacci numbers (because you do the same computation many times)

Comment: True, but it was the first, and simplest, double recursion example I could think of.  I suppose I could have shown QuickSort, but that's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

One interpertaion of double recursion could be divide and conquer (e.g) quicksort

```
quicksort = quicksort smaller ++ pivot ++ quicksort larger
```