# If function A calls function B and function B calls function A, is it technically a recursion?

Tags: recursion, terminology

How is recursion defined technically?

If

```
function A calls function B
function B calls function A
function A calls function B
function B calls function A
...
```

is it still considered to be recursion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the term for "double recursion"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586505/whats-the-term-for-double-recursion)

Comment: According to the dictionary recursion means referring to one's self. This isn't doing it directly so while I don't know the name I don't think it is necessarily recursion.

Comment: It may be recursion, see my next sentence. This is a different sentence, you should refer to the first sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Specifically it is nested recursion (aka [mutual recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion)).